# Como filtro apenas a data de um campo que tem data e hora definido?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Preciso criar um select no MySQL para filtrar o mês em uma tabela, porém o campo onde está definido a data, também tem definido a hora, dessa forma: [2017-02-04 10:00:00]

Como faço para filtrar apenas a data desse campo considerando apenas o mês e desconsiderando os outros valores como dia, ano e horas?

Comment: Pode fazer um cast para de `date` ou usar a função `date()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL - para retornar somente o mês

```
select MONTH(Nome_coluna) from Nome_tabela
```

Para retornar a data

```
select cast(Nome_coluna as date) from Nome_tabela
```

**E retornar a data considerando apenas o mês**

```
select cast(Nome_coluna as date) from Nome_tabela WHERE MONTH(Nome_coluna) = num_mes
```

sendo `num_mes` um numero de `1 a 12`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php) passando depois o formato que deseja que retorne. Por exemplo `date("m",$time)` para resgatar o mês. Veja:

```
$dateValue = "2017-02-04 10:00:00";
$time = strtotime($dateValue);
$month = date("m",$time);
```

Veja funcionando [no ideone](https://ideone.com/T1cdp0).